# Threads and context switch C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, x86, interrupt

I need help with understanding the following piece of code. It is an example of thread work and context switch written in C++(BC31 compiler).

I understand why the PCB exists in order to switch context (especially to keep the SS and the SP registers) and I also understand that it by using this the program can 
return to the point in which it was interrupted like nothing happened. About the code, I understand what the macros DISABLE_INTERRUPT and ENABLE_INTERRUPT are used for
(to ignore interruptions in some sensitive parts of the code). I also understand the function createProcess in which the local stack for every thread is created and the
flags, segments and offsets of the thread are written into it. In the function timerISR I understand the parts where the context switch is being done(writing and reading of SS and SP).

For the rest of the code, I can't say I understand it. What is the point of the functions returnNextThread(), initNewRoutine(), returnOldRoutine(), finishThread()?

Still, what I am most interested in is how is this program being run concurently, what actually happens there so that these three functions interlace while running...

How does all this work? 
I would really appreciate a simple explanation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<dos.h>

typedef struct PCB_struct {
    unsigned ss;
    unsigned sp;
    unsigned finished;
    unsigned quant;
} PCB;

#define DISABLE_INTERRUPT  asm cli
#define ENABLE_INTERRUPT  asm sti
PCB *threads[4];
volatile unsigned addressOfInterruptVector = 0x08;
volatile unsigned adressOfFreePlaceForInterrupt = 0x60;
volatile unsigned numberOfInterrupts=0;
volatile PCB *activeThread;
volatile unsigned activeThreadNumber=0;
volatile unsigned numberOfFinishedThreads=0;
volatile int necessarilyContextSwitch=0;

PCB* returnNextThread() {
    if(activeThreadNumber==0) {
        if(threads[1]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=1;
            return threads[1];
        }
        else if(threads[2]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=2;
            return threads[2];
        }
        else if(threads[3]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=3;
            return threads[3];
        }
        else {
            activeThreadNumber=0;
            return threads[0];
        }
    }
    else if(activeThreadNumber==1) {
        if(threads[2]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=2;
            return threads[2];
        }
        else if(threads[3]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=3;
            return threads[3];
        }
        else {
            activeThreadNumber=0;
            return threads[0];
        }
    }
    else if(activeThreadNumber==2) {
        if(threads[1]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=1;
            return threads[1];
        }
        else if(threads[3]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=3;
            return threads[3];
        }
        else {
            activeThreadNumber=0;
            return threads[0];
        }
    }
    else if(activeThreadNumber==3) {
        if(threads[2]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=2;
            return threads[2];
        }
        else if(threads[1]->finished==0) {
            activeThreadNumber=1;
            return threads[1];
        }
        else {
            activeThreadNumber=0;
            return threads[0];
        }
    }
    activeThreadNumber=0;
    return threads[0];
}

unsigned tmpSs=0;
unsigned tmpSp=0;
void interrupt timerISR() {
    if(!necessarilyContextSwitch) numberOfInterrupts--;
    if(numberOfFinishedThreads<3 && (numberOfInterrupts==0 || necessarilyContextSwitch==1)) {
        asm {
            mov tmpSs,ss
            mov tmpSp,sp
        }
        activeThread->ss=tmpSs;
        activeThread->sp=tmpSp;
        activeThread=returnNextThread();
        tmpSs=activeThread->ss;
        tmpSp=activeThread->sp;
        numberOfInterrupts=activeThread->quant;
        asm {
            mov ss,tmpSs
            mov sp,tmpSp
        }
    }
    if(!necessarilyContextSwitch) asm int 60h;
    necessarilyContextSwitch=0;
}

unsigned oldRoutineOffset, oldRoutineSegment;

void initNewRoutine() {
    unsigned offsetAddress=addressOfInterruptVector*4;
    unsigned segmentAddress=addressOfInterruptVector*4+2;
    unsigned emptyOffset=adressOfFreePlaceForInterrupt*4;
    unsigned emptySegment=adressOfFreePlaceForInterrupt*4+2;
    DISABLE_INTERRUPT 
    asm {
        push es
        push ax
        push di
        mov ax,0
        mov es,ax

        mov di, word ptr segmentAddress
        mov ax, word ptr es:di
        mov word ptr oldRoutineSegment, ax
        mov word ptr es:di, seg timerISR

        mov di, word ptr offsetAddress
        mov ax, word ptr es:di
        mov word ptr oldRoutineOffset, ax
        mov word ptr es:di, offset timerISR

        mov di, word ptr emptyOffset
        mov ax, word ptr oldRoutineOffset
        mov word ptr es:di, ax
        mov di, word ptr emptySegment
        mov ax, word ptr oldRoutineSegment
        mov word ptr es:di, ax

        pop di
        pop ax
        pop es
    }
    ENABLE_INTERRUPT 
}

void returnOldRoutine() {
    unsigned offsetAddress=addressOfInterruptVector*4;
    unsigned segmentAddress=addressOfInterruptVector*4+2;
    DISABLE_INTERRUPT 
    asm {
        push es
        push ax
        push di

        mov ax,0
        mov es,ax

        mov di, word ptr segmentAddress
        mov ax, word ptr oldRoutineSegment
        mov word ptr es:di, ax

        mov di, word ptr offsetAddress
        mov ax, word ptr oldRoutineOffset
        mov word ptr es:di, ax

        pop di
        pop ax
        pop es
    }
    ENABLE_INTERRUPT 
}

int finishThread() {
    necessarilyContextSwitch=1;
    DISABLE_INTERRUPT 
    activeThread->finished=1;
    cout << "Thread " << activeThreadNumber << " finished." << endl;
    ENABLE_INTERRUPT 
    timerISR();
    return 0;
}

void function1() {
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        cout << "Execution: function 1: " << i << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<30000;k++);
        }
    }
    finishThread();
}

void function2() {
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        cout << "Execution: function 2: " << i << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<30000;k++);
        }
    }
    finishThread();
}

void function3() {
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        cout << "Execution: function 3: " << i << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<30000;k++);
        }
    }
    finishThread();
}

void createProcess(PCB *block, void (*method)()) {
    unsigned* st1 = new unsigned[1024];

    st1[1023] = 0x200;          
    st1[1022] = FP_SEG(method);
    st1[1021] = FP_OFF(method);

    block->sp = FP_OFF(st1+1012);
    block->ss = FP_SEG(st1+1012);
    block->finished=0;
}

void mainThread() {

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        DISABLE_INTERRUPT 
        cout << "Main Thread: " << i << endl;
        ENABLE_INTERRUPT 
        for(int j=0;j<30000;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<30000;k++);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    DISABLE_INTERRUPT 
    threads[1]=new PCB();
    createProcess(threads[1], function1);
    threads[1]->quant=20;

    threads[2]=new PCB();
    createProcess(threads[2], function2);
    threads[2]->quant=40;

    threads[3]=new PCB();
    createProcess(threads[3], function3);
    threads[3]->quant=20;

    threads[0]=new PCB();
    activeThread=threads[0];
    activeThreadNumber=0;
    activeThread->quant=20;
    numberOfInterrupts=activeThread->quant;
    ENABLE_INTERRUPT 
    initNewRoutine();
    mainThread();
    returnOldRoutine();
    cout << "Main program finished." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful what you take from this code. C++ doesn't look much like this anymore.

Comment: @user4581301  I know that it doesn't look like this anymore, but I am in this kind of a situation where I need to use it as it is

Comment: Oh my. Whoever is doing this in the context of a class is a true sadist.

Comment: BC31 presumably means Borland C++ 3.1, which was released in 1992. I can't think of any reason to use a compiler of this vintage, and for an educator to inflict it on students is cruel and unusual punishment.

Comment: returnNextThread is not time slicing between the threads evenly. If the active thread is 2, then the order of checks should be 3, 1, 0 (instead of 1,3,0). If the active thread is 3, then the order of checks should be 1,2 0 (instead of 2,1,0). The way it's currently written, the scheduler cycles between threads 1 and 2 until one of them finishes before thread 3 is ever called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a home-grown task scheduler implemented on an very old CPU. You would probably need an extremely old system to have it running.

On the high level, the code functions as following:

- PCB blocks are just properties of every thread. They maintain the value of the 2 registers, slice (how long thread has spent on the CPU) and flag on whether it is finished
- When you create a new thread (process) this structure is initialized, but nothing else happens
- timerInterrupt is triggered by CPU automatically whenever time threshold elapses. Upon seeing the interrupt, interrupt handler analyzes the structures and switches to the appropriate thread by invoking CPU interrupt.

Answer (score 4):

That's horrible code (being old is no excuse). Anyway, the `timerISR` fires every so often and switches to the appropriate thread as determined by `returnNextThread` (which is basically the scheduler).

`finishThread` obviously ends a thread by marking it finished and forcing a context switch. Which part is unclear?

`initNewRoutine` and `returnOldRoutine` just install and uninstall the timer ISR (unfortunate naming).

Comment: Thank you. But,how is timerISR  called after a specific amount of time?
And,what is this assembler code with the address manipulation of the interrupt vectors used for?

Comment: That's set up by DOS already, the code just replaces the vector to point to the `timerISR` instead of the DOS handler. It makes a copy of the old handler at `int 60h` and chains to it.

Comment: @johnny94 there used to be [8253/8254 chip](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer) on the PC board (not sure if it's still used, I guess it's probably emulated by the modern chipset), which sets IRQ (interrupt request) pin on the CPU every time its counter does reach zero (it ticks at ~1.9MHz IIRC). If interrupts are not disabled (`CLI/STI` instructions), then the CPU upon detecting IRQ will check the interrupt table at the start of memory, and execute next instruction according to it, effectively executing the interrupt handler, instead of continuing with next instruction of app.